Allow all localhosts to make request to kong after removing * from allowed origins in CORS configuration
I have changed the CORS configuration to allow certain origins. However, this will also block local host users for development purposes. Is it possible to add all the localhost ports in the origin using some script in kong or is there another way that localhost can still work for development purposes?
I tried adding some porta manually but as there are many devs, they might be using other ports as well which is not added to the origins in kong.
I tried asking ChatGPT and it wrote a plugin but I haven't worked much on it so I didn't understand it. If anyone has any idea how we can achieve this via kong custom plugin, please do help. Thanks.

Welcome, but please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
